# How can I add assets fields

Tags: craftcms

I am new in craft CMS and currently I am working with craft fields module. But I don't know about assets fields.

So, can any one explain me how can I use assets Fields in Craft CMS?

Answer (score 0):

An asset field is more or less a reference to a file - more specifically, the value an asset field holds is actually an instance of an ElementCriteriaMode - you can loop over it to get the individual [AssetFileModel](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/assetfilemodel.html) instances. In the most general use case, you usually want to get the URI of the asset by calling the `.getUrl()` method on it and outputting it in your Twig template.

i.e.: `<img src={{ entry.assetField[0].getUrl() }}`>

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below screenshot to create any field with the "Assets" type.

[image]

Also, you can refer that how you can fetch the added entry using that field in front twig templates.
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets.html#example